# Unable to use S3 features of pyspark when loading the pyspark shell with Presto jar

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, presto

I want to use presto and be able to upload a file to s3. In a normal shell which I start with `pyspark` command, I can do that easily but when I load the presto jar with my pyspark shell, I face ClassNotFoundError.

The code that I run in both the shells is:

```
data = {'visitor': ['foo', 'bar', 'jelmer'], 'A': [0, 1, 0], 'B': [1, 0, 1], 'C': [1, 0, 0]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ddf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
ddf.write.csv("s3://my_bucket/test_with_no_keys_with_presto_jar")
```

In the shell `pyspark`, the code is successful. In the shell, `pyspark --driver-class-path com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver --jars presto-jdbc-0.221.jar`, I face the following error:

```
>>> ddf.write.csv("s3://demo-atlan-lake/test_with_no_keys_with_presto_jar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 927, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:524)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2367)
    ... 24 more
```

Note: I am running a spark cluster on AWS EMR.
I need to use presto, there is no compromise possible on that.

I was thinking if there is some mishap in using jar files in regular or only this one is causing the corruption?

I expect the code to run when using the presto jar.

## Update

I edited the spark-defaults-conf file and added the presto jar's file path. The new error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver
```

I have the following conf file after adding presto jar:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath      :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar:/home/hadoop/presto-jdbc-0.221.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.executor.extraClassPath    :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.sql.warehouse.dir          hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse
spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2
spark.yarn.historyServer.address ip-172-16-14-54.ap-south-1.compute.internal:18080
spark.history.ui.port            18080
spark.shuffle.service.enabled    true
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled  true
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.enabled true
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.timeout 1h
spark.resourceManager.cleanupExpiredHost true
spark.stage.attempt.ignoreOnDecommissionFetchFailure true
spark.decommissioning.timeout.threshold 20
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled false
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS $(hostname -f)
spark.files.fetchFailure.unRegisterOutputOnHost true
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem 2
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem true
spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled true
spark.sql.emr.internal.extensions com.amazonaws.emr.spark.EmrSparkSessionExtensions
spark.executor.memory            4269M
spark.executor.cores             4
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverheadFactor 0.1875
```